Django session creates new session key on every page refresh, causing duplicate carts
I am working on a Django app that uses user sessions to manage shopping carts. However, every time i refresh the page, a new session key is generated, which causes a new cart to be created. This results in multiple carts for the same user/session, which shouldn't happen. I'm try to understand why Django is creating a new session on every page refresh.
On reload of /products multiple sessions are created in django backend
[16/Sep/2024 17:11:31] "GET /api/products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 212
Session key: iedrvaus89536ly57pb242tnalwtx7vo
[16/Sep/2024 17:11:31] "GET /api/carts/retrieve_cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 107
[16/Sep/2024 17:11:31] "GET /api/products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 212
Session key: eipxdrmkf343fjtkchk7ads14ef1vccr
[16/Sep/2024 17:11:31] "GET /api/carts/retrieve_cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 107

If I click on add to cart I get two carts created:
    {
        "id": 77,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 66,
                "product": 1,
                "product_sku": "MNT-MST-MDL-HRV",
                "product_name": "Monthly Harvest Box",
                "product_price": 50.0,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2024-09-16T20:10:24.950541Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-09-16T20:10:24.950541Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 78,
        "items": [],
        "created_at": "2024-09-16T20:10:25.006548Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-09-16T20:10:25.006548Z"
    }

Here is ProductsPage.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './ProductsPage.css';
import Cart from './Cart';
import PictureGrid from "./PictureGrid";

const ProductsPage = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(null);  // Cart starts as null
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    const [loadingCart, setLoadingCart] = useState(true);  // For managing loading state

    // Fetch products from the Django API
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/products/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setProducts(data))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching products:', error));
    }, []);

    // Retrieve or create the cart for the current session
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!cart) {
            loadCart();  // Load the cart for the current session
        }
    }, [cart]);

    // Load cart items for the current session
    const loadCart = () => {
        setLoadingCart(true);  // Set loading state to true while loading cart
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/carts/retrieve_cart/`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(cartData => {
                setCart(cartData.id);  // Set the cart ID
                setCartItems(cartData.items);  // Set cart items
                calculateTotal(cartData.items);  // Calculate the total
                setLoadingCart(false);  // Set loading state to false after loading cart
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching cart data:', error);
                setLoadingCart(false);  // Set loading state to false even if there's an error
            });
    };

    // Calculate total price of the cart
    const calculateTotal = (items) => {
        const totalPrice = items.reduce((sum, item) => {
            const itemPrice = parseFloat(item.product_price);
            return sum + (itemPrice * item.quantity);
        }, 0);
        setTotal(totalPrice);
    };

    // Function to handle adding a product to the cart
    const addToCart = (productSku) => {
        if (!cart) {
            console.error('Cart not defined yet. Try again later.');
            return;
        }

        console.log('Adding product with SKU:', productSku);

        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/carts/${cart}/add_item`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ sku: productSku, quantity: 1 }),
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Product added to cart:', data);

                // Reload the cart after adding the item
                loadCart();
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error adding product to cart:', error));
    };

    // Function to handle removing a product from the cart
    const removeFromCart = (productSku) => {
        if (!cart) {
            console.error('Cart not defined yet. Try again later.');
            return;  // Prevent the function from running if cart is not yet defined
        }

        console.log('Removing product with SKU:', productSku);

        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/carts/${cart}/remove_item/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ sku: productSku }),
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`Error: ${response.statusText}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Item removed from cart:', data);
                const updatedCartItems = cartItems.filter(item => item.product_sku !== productSku);
                setCartItems(updatedCartItems);  // Update the cart items after removal
                calculateTotal(updatedCartItems);  // Recalculate the total
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error removing item from cart:', error));
    };

    return (
        <div className="products-page">
            <PictureGrid />
            <h2>Our Subscriptions</h2>
            <div className="products-grid">
                {products.map(product => (
                    <div className="product-card" key={product.sku}>
                        <img src={"box.jpg"} alt={product.name} className="product-image" />
                        <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                        <p>Price: ${product.price}</p>
                        <button className="buy-button" onClick={() => addToCart(product.sku)} disabled={loadingCart}>
                            {loadingCart ? 'Loading...' : 'Add to Cart'}
                        </button>
                        <p>SKU: {product.sku}</p>
                    </div>  
                ))}
            </div>

            {/* Include the Cart component */}
            <Cart cartItems={cartItems} total={total} removeFromCart={removeFromCart} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductsPage;

Everything had worked until I transitioned carts to work via session. What am I doing wrong?

Do you have this SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST set to True?

# Use the database to store session data SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
# Set session cookie settings SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid' SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
# Set session expiry SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
# Save the session to the database on every request SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

Can you post the contents of views.py which contains the request handlers for /api/carts/retrieve_cart/ and /api/products/ ?
